# Exchangability of inner product and integral in bochner spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, probability-theory, operator-theory, bochner-spaces

For the linear operator $e \in \mathcal{L}(V,V^{*})$,  and suﬃciently small $\delta s \in V := L^2(0,T,L^2(D))$ and $p \in V$ we have;
$$ E[\langle e^{*}p, \delta s \rangle_{V}] = \langle E[e^{*} p ] , \delta s \rangle_{V^{*},V} $$
Why this relation is true?

$D \subsetneq \mathbb{R}$ and $T \in \mathbb{R}$ is a real number.

A similar question was asked in
[Exchangeability of inner product with the integral](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/60688/exchangeability-of-inner-product-with-the-integral/540111#540111)
by @jpv, I have extended the question and propose a proof for that, but I am not completely sure about that proof.

Comment: I do not understand your notation nor your question.

Comment: Thank you Dear @gerw, I modified my question. If again the question have errors, I'll pleased to hear.